# Android Studio Strange Logcat output

Tags: java, android, listview

When I run my app on my Droid Turbo, by Motorola with Android version 5.1 everything works perfectly fine. In fact this has been my main testing device, and it has worked fine throughout.

However, I got new a device to test different screen sizes and Android version. So I borrow my friends Samsung SIII Android version: 4.4.4. And when I run it, it runs into the logcat issues below. The application is supposed to scan for Bluetooth devices and list them in a ListView, however, it messes up and displays a single item dozens of times with those warnings.

> 01-21 12:08:01.941 4280-4280/com.relcominc.fbt_12 I/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find method
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>
> 01-21 12:08:01.941 4280-4280/com.relcominc.fbt_12 W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 458:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
>
> 01-21 12:08:01.941 4280-4280/com.relcominc.fbt_12 D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
>
> 01-21 12:08:01.941 4280-4280/com.relcominc.fbt_12 I/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced
>   from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
>
> 01-21 12:08:01.941 4280-4280/com.relcominc.fbt_12 W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 480:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
>
> 01-21 12:08:01.941 4280-4280/com.relcominc.fbt_12 D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002

Any potential solutions you guys can think of?

Also, here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.relcominc.fbt_12"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 15
        versionName "Alpha"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:v1.5.8'
    compile project(':snakeyaml-1.10-android')
}
```

Comment: The logcat window has a search at the right side. insert in there your progect name i.e  com.myproject.whatever -- do you still see those warnings?

Comment: Yes, it has my package name in it: com.relcominc.fbt_12

Comment: my bad, i didn't notice those messages are clearly coming  from com.relcominc.fbt_12 -- its a bit suspect the warning are produced by android.support.v7.widget -- try the zero version -- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0  -- http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: @Tasos I went ahead and tried that, and still no luck. My initial thoughts on this was that Android might be bundled with different versions of the support library. My newer phone 5.1, has appcompat-v7:23.1.1 built in, however my older phone 4.4.4, doesn't which causes there to be runtime errors like we are seeing. But this is just a theory and i don't know how to go about proving or solving this theory. Any help?